# Redirect some customs urls and redirect the rest to frontpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've moved from an old site to another domain.
I have allready set up 301 redirects for the exacts urls and articles I wish to keep. The rest of the site I wish to go to frontpage of anotherdomain.com
How do I do this ?

Comment: By implementing redirection rules. Start by reading the documentation of the tool you use. Here apache's rewriting module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

My .htacces looks like this:

RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /news2/ http://newdomain/news2/
Redirect 301 /product/product1 http://newdomain.dk/articleaboutproducts

I wish all the rest urls including the frontpage and 404 error sites to redirect to frontpage of newdomain.com.